# Is it possible to change the ground voltage level for the ADC/DAC at a STM32F373?

Tags: stm32, adc, dac

I want to change the ADC and the DAC ground so the ADC begins to measure at e.g `0.64V` and the DAC begins to send out voltage at `0.64V`.

Is it possible to change `VSSA` and `VSSSD`

[image]

One issue I found is that `VSSA` can only be `0V`. But `0V` just a difference point. We can say that `0.64V` is the zero-ground-voltage. Right? Or can't I change `VSSA` and `VSSSD`?

[image]

Datasheet: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f373cc.pdf

Comment: What you can do is use a voltage divider from Vdda to generate your 0.64V and feed that to the input of your adc from a voltage follower, so there is always an 0.64V offset

Comment: @ChrisD91 Is that really possible? I mean, Vref- is bounded to ground.

Comment: If all you want to do is ensure that ADC never reads below 0.64V or reads 0.64V when there is no signal present then yes you can bias the ADC. However if you want the ADC to read between 0.64V-3.3V (I'm assuming vref is 3.3V) and maintain full resolution, say a full 1024 bits between that voltage range then no it is impossible unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Absolute maximum ratings* section on p. 55 of the linked datasheet the specs tell you, that the voltage difference between different Vss pins can't exceed 50mV.

[image]